# Unix programming - delete lines between 2 words

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file in which I want to delete some lines which comes in between ().

Example:

```
ABC
Bcd
Test(
Xyz
Pqr)
Lmn
Klm
Test(
Hij
Ijk)
Eric
```

I want the output to be

```
ABC
Bcd
Lmn
Klm
Eric
```

Please help me to get this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st Solution:***

```
awk -v flag=1 '/\)/{flag=1;next} /\(/{flag=""} flag'   Input_file
```

***2nd Solution:*** With `sed` also you could try following.

```
sed  '/(/,/)/d'  Input_file
```

Comment: Slight nitpick - naming a flag variable `flag` is like naming a numeric variable `number`. Technically accurate but not nearly as useful as naming the variable for what it represents. Just like a numeric variable could be named `count` or `sum` or `cost` or any of a million other names for what numeric variables **represent**, so too flag variables should be named for what they **represent** - `foundValue` or `inBlock` or `reachedLimit`, etc. FYI when a flag variable is named `f` (as it often is) that `f` is not an abbreviation for  **f**lag, it's an abbreviation for  **f**ound.

Comment: @EdMorton, you are a mind reader too, you caught it right, will keep in mind, thanks.

Comment: @keerthi, could you please do let me know the reason for removing this as correct answer, could try to improve it if possible, try to select any of the given answers as correct answer to close the thread completely too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
awk '/\(/,/\)/{next}1' input_filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/\(/{f=1} !f; /\)/{f=0}' file
```